# how to disable list item's attachment using coding in custom field of sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

how to disable list item's attachment using coding in sharepoint 2010
Please help. I will provide further screen shots if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this via the SPList object using the EnableAttachments property.  Here's a PowerShell example.

```
$web = $site.OpenWeb();
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]
$list.EnableAttachments = $false
$list.Update()
```